# Why isnt this clickable drop down menu showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down menu that when hovered over works and I added a some javascript that toggles a css class .show-menu on and off when click and removes the hover css for mobile devices. My problem is the menu isn't showing when clicked. I can see in the dev tools that the css class is being removed and added, so the javascript is working fine., so it seems to be a css issue. however I'm failing to see any css conflicts that would be causing this issue. Does anyone have any idea what the issue is here?-thanks

I added the entire css sheet in the jsfiddle as I'm clearly missing something
https://jsfiddle.net/kmut5xtu/

```
        <nav>
             <ul class="main-nav">  
                 <li class="main-nav-item current-page"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-item characters">
                    <span>Characters</span>
                    <ul class="drop-menu">
                        <li class="drop-menu-back"><span class="material-icons">arrow_back</span>Back</li>
                        <li><a href="characters.html%20#ethan-clarke">Ethan Clarke</a></li>          
                        <li><a href="characters.html%20#serena-kiriaga">Serena Kiriaga</a></li>
                        <li><a href="characters.html%20#marcus-flynn">Marcus Flynn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="characters.html%20#emily-ashdown">Emily Ashdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="characters.html%20#miles-west">Director Miles West</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="auther.html">Author</a></li>
             </ul>
        </nav>


    !function app(){

        !function AddMenuClickHandler(){
                let charTab= document.querySelector(".characters");
                let toggle= 1;

                charTab.addEventListener("click",function(){
                    let dropMenu=document.querySelector(".drop-menu");
                    if(toggle===1){
                        dropMenu.classList.add("show-menu");
                        toggle=0;
                    }
                    else if(toggle===0){
                        dropMenu.classList.remove("show-menu");
                        toggle=1;
                    }
                })
            }()
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

The css below is the issue:

```
.characters:hover {
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
            }
    .characters:hover .drop-menu{
             visibility: visible;
             opacity:1;
        }
```

Remove hover from these css and you will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Off the bat, you need to tell your HTML that you are using JS. You do this with script tags:

```
<script>
  Your code here
</script>
```

While I don't personally use JS to disable clickable menus on phones, there is a really simple way to just make them clickable that [BootStrap uses](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp), which, if you use BootStrap, will allow you to easily modify things for mobile views.